# Conditional merge of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Have two dataframes:

[image: DataFrames]

How to merge df1 with df2 so that we get the following result is obtained based 
 on X:

```
Ticker   Type   Date
======   ====   ====
OEX      Index  2018-06-01
XEO      Index  2018-06-01
SPX      Index  2018-06-01
SPX      Index  2018-06-08
SPX      Index  2018-06-22
```

...and so on...

## df1:

```
    Ticker  Type    Std_Week    EOW
    ======  ====    ========    ===
12  OEX     Index   X           NaN
13  XEO     Index   X           NaN
14  SPX     Index   NaN         X
15  XSP     Index   NaN         X
```

## df2:

```
    Std_Week             EOW
    ========             ===
0   2018-06-01 00:00:00  2018-06-01 00:00:00
1   NaN                  2018-06-08 00:00:00
2   NaN                  2018-06-22 00:00:00
3   NaN                  2018-06-29 00:00:00
4   NaN                  2018-07-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: Post `df1` and `df2` as text

Comment: df1
Ticker Type Std_Week EOW
12 OEX Index X NaN
13 XEO Index X NaN
14 SPX Index NaN X
15 XSP Index NaN X

df2
Std_Week EOW
0 2018-06-01 00:00:00 2018-06-01 00:00:00
1 NaN 2018-06-08 00:00:00
2 NaN 2018-06-22 00:00:00
3 NaN 2018-06-29 00:00:00
4 NaN 2018-07-06 00:00:00

Comment: How to do it? Clipboard paste gives the data put in comment.

Comment: Updated with text

Comment: IMHO there's no obvious logic behind what you describe. How is the relation computed, which row of df2 should be taken? X tells which column, but which row remains unclear; please clarify

Comment: @SpghttCd It is for every row of df1. Each row in df1 has at least one column with an X. If a row has one column with an X, it should generate one * no of rows in that df2.column. If a row has two columns with X it should generate two rows * (no of rows in df2.column1 + no of rows in df2.column2) in the output with the dates in df2.